# condition javascript statement throws exception vs inline condition

Tags: javascript

The following conditional statement throws an exception when the value is not defined:

```
if (!(e = e[f])) {
    e[f] = {};
}
```

while the following inline condition doesn't throw any exception:

```
e = e[f] ? e[f] : e[f] = {};
```

Here is the function that contains the condition, it's responsible for creating objects dynamically starting from the window object:

```
function t(a, c) {
    var s = a.split('.'),
        e = window;
    // works only in IE
    !(s[0] in e) && e.execScript && e.execScript('var '+ s[0]);
    for (var f; s.length && (f = s.shift()); ) {
        if (!s.length && void 0 !== c) {
            e[f] = c;
        }else {
            e = e[f] ? e[f] : e[f] = {};
        }
    }
}
```

An example for calling this function:

```
t('s.d');
```

This call should create a new Object: `window.s.d`

Does anyone have any idea about what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The first case:

```
if (!(e = e[f])) {
    e[f] = {};
}
```

You're setting `e` (which was set to the `window` object) to its `.s` property (i.e `t('s.d')`). This property is undefined, and "notting" this with `!` will return true, effectively making the statement pass. On the next line `e` is still undefined, and when you do

```
e[ f ] = {};
```

It translates to:

```
undefined[ f ] = {};
```

This is what is causing the error.

### The second (ternary) case:

```
e = e[f] ? e[f] : e[f] = {};
```

This is parsed as:

```
e = (e[f]) ? e[f] : e[f] = {};
```

and **not** as

```
(e = e[f]) ? e[f] : e[f] = {};
```

If it were parsed in the latter case, you would get the same error as with the conditional case because the first operand (`e[f]`) will return undefined, going to the false case of the ternary operator (`e[f] = {}`). This will translate also to `undefined[f] = {}` which would cause the error.

Comment: i'm sorry i just updated the code, the following snippets should be equal: e = e[f] ? e[f] : e[f] = {}; and if (!(e = e[f])) e[f] = {};

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down:

1. `e = e[f]`, it's an assignment.

   `e` will be assigned `undefined` if `e[f]` doesn't exist.
2. `!(e = e[f])` is `true`.

   This statement is `true` because `e` doesn't contain a property called `f`.
3. `if (!(e = e[f])) { ... }`, then the condition is met.
4. `if( ... ){ e[f] = {}; }`.

   At this point `e` holds the value `undefined`. This translates to `undefined[f] = {}`, hence the error.

Comment: i'm sorry i just updated the code, the following snippets should be equal: e = e[f] ? e[f] : e[f] = {}; and if (!(e = e[f])) e[f] = {};